# How to play youtube URL through Android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to play videos using Androind MediaPlayer with url to a youtube video?

Instead of it playing through youtube i would like for it to play through the MediaPlayer locally on the device.

How would i go about doing this?

EDIT: sorry for the title

Comment: The question's title has nothing to do with the actual question. Please update it accordingly.

Comment: That was an accident. sorry. Its fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer.setDataSource(url) might do the trick.  More guidance [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html).